# Asynchronous Callbacks to Dismissed Viewcontrollers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, asynchronous, modalviewcontroller

Have noticed issue while testing iphone app that if one quickly opens/dismisses a modal view which contains asynchronous http calls the app eventually freezes up with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS message.  I'm relatively confident that there aren't any memory leaks in either the modal view or the viewcontroller that's launching it (at least none that I can find via the leak detection tool in xcode).  My n00b mind wonders what happens with pending asynchronous callbacks when all of a sudden the view has been dismissed.  Is this something I should be concerned about, or does the iPhone OS handle this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should retain the view controller in your HTTP request class or if you don't have an abstraction class, retain and release itself in the delegate methods.

Comment: Accept as answer, pretty please?

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, have your view controller un-set itself as the delegate for pending HTTP requests in dealloc.